# Calculator for magic item creation in RPG

Tags: beginner, f#, role-playing-game

I have created a simple calculator that will assist in creating magic items from the tabletop RPG Pathfinder. [Here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) are the full requirements, and if you want a more concise version, [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l171GFwtRutLXfjitJWfMdbas45Dd9z-ApMhKa7R8pg/edit?pli=1) is a player generated summary of the process.

I have been trying to get into F# and functional programming in general. I come from a strong object-oriented background and it has been difficult in ignoring those habits. Please focus on whether or not this is idiomatic F#. I would love to hear if there is a better way to write any of it. And, if you find bug, I'd be happy to know that too.

## Questions

A couple of things specifically that I feel could be better would be the DC calculation. I wasn't sure how to approach applying the rush function only if the item was rushed. I also tried finding a place where I could apply functional composition, but I think I needed all the intermediate steps that I stop on.

## Code

```
let baseDC casterLevel =
    5 + casterLevel

let rush dc =
    dc + 5

let ignoreRequirements requirements dc =
    dc + (5 * requirements)

let getBuildPrice basePrice =
    basePrice * 0.5

let getTime basePrice =
    floor (8.0 * basePrice / 1000.0)

let getMinBonusForNoCursed dc =
    dc - 6

let buildDaysWhileAdventuring isRushed buildTime =
    let adventuringBuildTime = buildTime / 4.0
    floor (if isRushed then adventuringBuildTime else adventuringBuildTime * 2.0)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let isRushed = true
    let casterLevel = 1
    let requirementsIgnored = 1

    let basePrice = 5000.0
    let buildPrice = getBuildPrice basePrice

    let buildTime = getTime basePrice
    let daysAdventuring = buildDaysWhileAdventuring isRushed buildTime

    let DC = 
        match isRushed with
        | false -> baseDC casterLevel |> ignoreRequirements requirementsIgnored
        | true -> baseDC casterLevel |> ignoreRequirements requirementsIgnored |> rush

    let minDC = getMinBonusForNoCursed DC

    printfn "Min/DC: %i/%i Cost: %.2f Days/Hours: %.1f/%.1f" minDC DC
        buildPrice daysAdventuring buildTime

    0 // Return code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems with this, most notably, you have a *plethora* of magic numbers.

> ```
> let baseDC casterLevel =
>     5 + casterLevel
>
> let rush dc =
>     dc + 5
>
> let ignoreRequirements requirements dc =
>     dc + (5 * requirements)
>
> let getBuildPrice basePrice =
>     basePrice * 0.5
>
> let getTime basePrice =
>     floor (8.0 * basePrice / 1000.0)
>
> let getMinBonusForNoCursed dc =
>     dc - 6
>
> let buildDaysWhileAdventuring isRushed buildTime =
>     let adventuringBuildTime = buildTime / 4.0
>     floor (if isRushed then adventuringBuildTime else adventuringBuildTime * 2.0)
> ```

In order, I see:

1. `5 + casterLevel`: what is `5`?
2. `dc + 5`: what is `5`? Is it the same as #1?
3. `5 * requirements`: what is `5`? Is it the same as #1 or #2?
4. `basePrice * 0.5`: what is `0.5`? Is it `1 / 2` or something different?
5. `8.0 * basePrice`: what is `8.0`?
6. `#5 / 1000.0`: what is `1000.0`?
7. `dc - 6`: what is `6`?
8. `buildTime / 4.0`: what is `4.0`?
9. `adventuringBuildTime * 2.0`: what is `2.0`, is it `4.0 / 2`, is it the `4.0` from #8 / 2?

---

For a functional program, it's not too bad. I don't like how many times you use `if` (I always prefer `match`), but when dealing with boolean types it does quite fine.